# /etc/environment not being read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, environment-variables

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

```
cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
RAILS_ENV=production
```

yet

```
echo $RAILS_ENV
<blank>
```

I've got another VPS that this works properly on.  Only difference I can think of is root login and password logins are disabled on the non-working server.  Exiting the ssh session and restarting the server do not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What does `sudo su -l root $PATH` return ?

It might well be that you need to assign variables like this

```
X="Something"
Y="Another Thing $x"
```

Note that here Y is just equal to "Another Thing $X" and not "Another Thing Something" as you might expect. I.e this file is assignment only and not a script file. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: `-su: /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/bin:/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/home/deployer/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games: No such file or directory`. Not sure why I'm getting the no such file error

Comment: Try wrap the production in quotes so RAILS_ENV = "production"

Comment: Quotes didn't seem to change anything.  I read somewhere that `/etc/environment` is read as part of the PAM process.  I have UsePAM set to no in my sshd.conf file, so maybe that is a problem?

Comment: Also you need to log out and in again for changes to take effect. I.e there is no way to 'source' this file

Comment: Heads up, the logging out/in didn't fix it.  I can't seem to find much documentation on what `etc/environment` actually does, and therefore can't really be sure about that PAM thing

Comment: Try here http://superuser.com/questions/339617/how-to-reload-etc-environment-without-rebooting

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38377/discussion-between-tyler-dewitt-and-avrono)

Answer (score 0):

Has a similar issue here.

Fixed it by using Figaro gem.

http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html